# how using django-filebrowser at apache?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

hi all:
  I have a quirky question about django-filebrowser,

---

my project at /home/q/django/myapp,
  I save the django-filebrowser at /home/q/django/myapp/filebrowser .

```
 **myapp.settings.py**
  INSTALLED_APPS=(
    .....
    myapp.filebrowser,
    ....

 )   
  **myapp.urls.py**
   urlpatterns=patterns('',
    (r'filebrowser/',(include("filebrowser.usls")),
    ....
   )
```

everything is look like the tutorials [http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/wiki/installationbasic .](http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/wiki/installationbasic)

but it's not work.when I saved the django-filebrowser to django's directory:/usr/local/lib/python2.6/.... it's work fine.

so,if I want modify some settings,I need change the filebrowser.settings.py at the django root directory(/usr/local/lib/...),not my project directory(/home/q/django/myapp/filebrowser)

I think its not advisable.someone could get me any advice? 
  &_& 
    THKS

```
my os:ubuntu 10.04
django version :1.24
grappelli:3.X
python version:2.6(own system)
web server:apache+mod_python
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify all the settings, including those of django-filebrowser, in `myapp.settings`. The `settings.py` in `filebrowser` are the default values used if you don't specify them in your own settings. This is a widely used pattern for 3rd party django apps to define default values for settings.

If you look at [`filebrowser.settings`](http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/source/browse/trunk/filebrowser/settings.py), you'll see this line almost at the top:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

That line imports Django's settings module, which contains Django's default settings, overridden by the settings you defined in `myapp.settings`.

Further down in `filebrowser.settings`, there are lines like

```
DIRECTORY = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY", 'uploads/')
```

This assigns the value `myapp.settings.FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY` to `DIRECTORY`, or, if you haven't defined that setting, the default value `'uploads/'`.

BTW: I would avoid mod_python like the plague. It's unsupported, unmaintained and generally a pain. There's a much better alternative: [mod_wsgi](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/)